# set background position to top in wordpress

Tags: css, wpbakery

I am using Wordpress and WPbakery. I have set a full-width, full-height background. But currently the background-position is set to centred with '!important' assigned as I see in the developer tools.

I want to set it to 'top'. I edited in developer tools in chrome and I achieved the desired effect. However I'm not sure how to make the changes permanent. I have tried copy pasting what I saw in the developer tools into the custom css field and editing it to 'top' but it wont override the theme. How do i go about it?

This is the current code seen in developer tools:

```
.vc_custom_1551104319445 {
background-image: url(https://unlicensedshrink.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/ulweb.jpg?id=9) !important;
background-position: center !important;
background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
background-size: cover !important;
```

}

Comment: Not sure in which order custom styles and the default CSS of the theme are output … try increasing the specificity of our selector, f.e. like `html .vc_custom_1551104319445` or `.vc_custom_1551104319445.vc_custom_1551104319445`

Comment: Thank you! with a 'html' in front, it worked! do you mind explaining to me why? or point me to an article that explains it?

Comment: Gave a bit more detailed explanation in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure in which order custom styles and the default CSS of the theme are output … try increasing the specificity of your selector, f.e. like `html .vc_custom_1551104319445` or `.vc_custom_1551104319445.vc_custom_1551104319445`

When multiple CSS rules apply to an element and try to specify values for the same properties, it becomes a matter of **specificity**, which one “wins”.

Here are a few resources on that topic:
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity
https://specificity.keegan.st/

So if you try to overwrite something using the exact same selector you took from the WP/themes styles, it becomes simply a matter of order. Do the WP styles get embedded last? Then they win, otherwise yours would.

A simple way around that, is to increase the specificity of your selector. Selecting elements of this class on the additional “condition” that are descendants of the `html` element is one way to do that. Or to repeat the class name, so that `.foobar` becomes `.foobar.foobar` … and lots of other possible ways.

Answer (score 0):

You need to see which file is producing the code. For instance - [image: Highlighted file]

After you know which file is responsible for the code, then you go to the site directory and implement the file in question.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't suggest using the vc_ number selector. Best to use or even better add a custom selector on the row or element itself and then apply the following CSS.

```
.has-bgimg-right.vc_row-has-fill{
   background-position:center right !important;
}
```

What ends up happening if you use the vc_ number selector is if you or your client go to update that field the vc number will change and you will be shaking your head. So create a custom selector class and use the vc_row-has-fill which will never change.